# OV7670 Camera Module - wrong pins?

Tags: i2c

I would like to ask you some helpful informations.

Recently I bought an OV7670 Camera Module.
Unfortunately, this item is not compatible with any tutorial I found in dozens and dozens of sites.

It has 18 pins with these signs:

```
3.3v   GND
SCL    SDA
VS     HS
PCLK   MCLK
D7     D6
D5     D4
D3     D2
D1     D0
RESET  PWDN
```

I aint noticed these pins on any OV7670 Camera in any site of tutorial, like youtube or arduino.cc or many others at google searching.
The most comon OV7670 Cameras I found in tutorials have SIOC SIOD instead of SCL SDA, HREF instead of HS and XCLK instead of MCLK.
Did I bought a fake or what do you think?
Please, if any of you, knows how to make it conect or have any useful link, I will apreciate to inform me.
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 3):

They are actually named in a different manner.

Your camera module has i2c interface.

SIOC is nothing but Serial Input Clock , same as SCL - i2c clock

Similarly , SDA and SIOD are the same - i2c data

HREF and HS are the same too - Hsync signal

MCLK and XCLK are the same too - system clock

Here is a useful link:

https://www.google.co.in/amp/www.instructables.com/id/OV7670-Arduino-Camera-Sensor-Module-Framecapture-T/%3famp_page=true

Cheers !